# Variables in PHP Array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

So i have the code below basically when its run it will display a graph. How can i make the variables inside the arrays work the variable works and when echoed will give a number but for some reason it doesn't input number there. $mar1 in [here]

```
$lineChart = new gLineChart($_GET['width'],$_GET['height']);
[here]$lineChart->addDataSet(array($mar1,315,66,40));[/here]
$lineChart->setLegend(array("first"));
$lineChart->setColors(array("ff3344", "11ff11", "22aacc", "3333aa"));
$lineChart->setVisibleAxes(array('x','y'));
$lineChart->setDataRange(30,400);
$lineChart->addAxisLabel(0, array("This", "axis", "has", "labels!"));
$lineChart->addAxisRange(1, 30, 400);
$lineChart->setGridLines(0, 15);
$lineChart->renderImage();
```

Comment: Where are you declaring `$mar1`? Show that.

Comment: here  $mar1 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE `status` = '1' AND `pid` = '$publisher_id' AND `month` = '03'"));

Answer (score 0):

This is a very, very basic question about PHP syntax.  Arrays **can** and frequently are used with variable data.

There isn't anything wrong with the syntax of the code that you posted, so chances are that this is a case of the `$mar1` variable not being defined or not containing the data that you're expecting.  You probably want to `echo` or `var_dump` this variable and see what's in it and work backwards from there.

If `$mar1` doesn't contain what you expect, look in the code above that line and see if its value is being set.  If this is being passed in the browser's query string like the `$_GET['width']` and `$_GET['height']` variables are, you would need to access it as `$_GET['mar1']` instead of just `$mar1`.

If this file is being included from another file or includes/requires other files, it could also be defined in the including file(s).

If `$mar1` does contain the value you're expecting, then check the documentation for the `gLineChart` class and make sure that you're passing it all the correct parameters.